# Cosmic Inflation Model software

Tags: cosmology

I'm writing a small/medium sized proposal for my Master's research project where I intend to write a piece of software/sequence of programs which takes users models for scalar fields' equations of motion (as regular or differential equations I assume, I'm going to read some more papers on different models after posting), couples them to the Friedman equation, simulates a universe with those characteristics and turns them into the primordial power spectrum and observables (through a Boltzmann solver) for the user to analyse their models/play around with.

I won't be able to speak to my supervisor for a few days, and would like to check some things just so I can get a decent proposal together in time to present it next Friday.

Besides how to get from a primordial power spectrum to observables, all of the first paragraph has been my supervisors idea, who has a lot of research in cosmology and inflation.

I wanted to check with you guys about how if it's possible to, and the steps in getting from the equations of motion to the spectral index.

If anyone knows of any software or programs that do this, please let me know as I'm proposing that this has not been done before.

Thank you in advance for any answers, comments or suggestions :)

Comment: This has been done before.  See CAMB (https://camb.info/readme.html): it's the premier software for computing the temperature spectrum of the CMB.  It assumes a power spectrum parameterized in terms of $n_s$ and $\alpha$.

Regarding a numerical computation of the power spectra from a general inflation potential, this has also been investigated (see, e.g.https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0703625.pdf).  But, a question first: if you are obtaining the spectra numerically, what need is there for the spectral parameters like $n_s$?  What do you plan to do with the models after you've generated them?